# jQuery UI autocomplete doesn't work in rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I want to use jQuery UI autocomplete function in my rails app. I get a example in [jQuery website](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) and want to make it in my rails app. `jquery-rails` and `jquery-ui-rails` all have been installed.

I added the below codes to `application.js`

```
$(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
    ];
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

add some codes to `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags">
</div>
```

but doesn't autocomplete when I input something(like: "ja"..)

Anyone can help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: i would suggest you too check the console for any errors, also if possible why dont you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

**In your gemfile**

```
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
`bundle install`
```

**In your application.js**

```
//= require autocomplete-rails
```

**In your controller**

```
autocomplete :model_name, :column_name, :full => true
```

**In your routes**

```
resources :controller_name do
  get :autocomplete_model_name_column_name, :on => :collection
end
```

**In your view**

```
<%= autocomplete_field_tag 'column_name', '', autocomplete_model_name_column_name_controller_name_path %>
```

Comment: thanks for help, maybe it can works, but i don't want to add more gems